# Update values in mongodb from node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Below is the code I have tried to update the values in mongoDB but it is not working and showing an error while I am trying to update the values.
The error which is coming is :

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: agastyaforonewaydevelopmentstaging.deviceinfos.$_id_  dup key: { : \"355537056685953\" }",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "errmsg": "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: agastyaforonewaydevelopmentstaging.deviceinfos.$_id_  dup key: { : \"355537056685953\" }"
}
```

And the code is:

```
 // mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@ds031671.mongolab.com:31671/oneway', function(err) {
if (err) {
    console.log('connection error', err);
} else {
    console.log('connection successful');
}
});

var deviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
    },
    MobileNum: Number,
    Fecode: String
})

var deviceinfo = mongoose.model('deviceinfo', deviceSchema);

// Device collection close

app.get('/feature', function(req, res) {
    res.render('feature.ejs', {
    user: req.user
    });
});
app.get('/feature', function(req, res) {

    res.render('feature.ejs');
});
app.post('/feature', function(req, res) {
    // if(collection.findOne({_id:req.body.Imei}))
    new deviceinfo({
    _id: req.body.Imei,
    MobileNum: req.body.Mobile,
    Fecode: req.body.fecode
    }).save(function(err, drd) {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    else
        res.render('feature.ejs');
    });
});

app.get('/fupdate', function(req, res) {

    res.render('upfeature.ejs');
});

app.post('/fupdate', function(req, res) {
    // if(collection.findOne({_id:req.body.Imei}))
    new deviceinfo({
    _id: req.body.Imei,
    MobileNum: req.body.Mobile,
    Fecode: req.body.fecode
    }).update(function(err, drd) {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    else
        res.render('feature.ejs');
    });
});
```

How to rectify the error?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid updating document using new object model of existing _id

Instead you can update a document by passing _id as query string

```
app.post('/fupdate/:Imei', function(req, res) {
    deviceinfo.findById(req.params.Imei, function(err, device) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        device.MobileNum = req.body.Mobile;
        device.Fecode = req.body.fecode;
        device.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'device updated!' });
        });

    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but now I need to change in edit button also so that while click on the button it should select the id.

Comment: Change your button href attr value to "/fupdate/<%= drd._id %>"

Comment: Are you getting same error while clicking update button or different error

Comment: It is showing an error like path cant be empty. Is it possible for you to share your  email id so that I can send you the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Check your error, it clearly states

```
duplicate key error index:
```

Which means you are trying to duplicate an index(e.g. have it twice), and you can't have that.

I checked out your code again, and i noticed you have

```
app.get('/feature'
```

Twice. Is there any reason for that?

PS: MongoDB says you have the same ID twice, which probably means there's something wrong in your front-end(back-end seems fine), and you're sending the same value.

Edit: If you want to update a record, you have to use the update method of Mongoose. Here's what the docs have to say about it http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html
Otherwise you're just trying to create a new record with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

@Raja 
How to change the edit button so that while clicking on that it should select the id.

The edit option I have given as a link which open a page on click.Below is the code :

```
     <table class="table table-bordered"> 
     <tbody>

         <tr>
              <td><%= drd._id %></td>
    <td><%= drd.MobileNum %></td>
          <td><%= drd.Fecode %></td>
    <td> <a class="button" href="/fupdate"><img src="/images/edit.png" width="20" height="20"></a></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```